# (make/g++) include full path of auto-generated dependency targets? (or workaround)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, g++, makefile, googletest

[short version]
I can't have two source files with the same name in my unit tested c++ project even though they are in different folders. g++ and make are grumpy with each other. (Or maybe I'm being stupid)

[long version]
I've run into a problem with my make/g++/gtest setup. When g++ auto-generates dependencies, it generates something like this:

```
event_handler.o: src/os/event_handler.h src/os/event.h
```

But I need something like this (full path of target):

```
src/os/event_handler.o: src/os/event_handler.h src/os/event.h
```

The reason is when I have a file like this:

```
src/os/event_handler.cpp // contains EventHandler class
```

I have a companion file like this:

```
test/src/os/event_handler.cpp // contains EventHandlerTest unit test class
```

... so their .o files both just show up as event_handler.o in the auto-generated dependency list. Is there a way to force g++ to give the full path or do I need to change the names of my test files to something like:

```
test/src/os/event_handler_test.cpp
```

I wasn't able to find anything online or in the documentation.

Comment: I would advise using names like `event_handler_test.cpp` and maybe `event_stub.cpp`, but you can also use full paths; can you show us your makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions.

1. Use -MMD to compile and create dependencies in one step, which will generate .d files corresponding to the object files.
2. Use -MT or -MQ to specify the path to the object when generating prerequisites.

Personally I prefer the MMD solutions, as it also tends to work better with buggy header files. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html